# How to use clap to take create a vector

Tags: rust, clap

I have a basic struct like this

```
pub struct Args {
  #[clap(short, long, value_parser)]
  pub files: Vec<String>,
}
```

I'm trying to get this struct to take multiple values like such

```
cargo run -- --files hello world
```

But when I run this, it doesn't see `world` correctly. It errors with this:

```
error: Found argument 'world' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

What is the proper way to have clap populate this struct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`num_args`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.num_args) to specify a range for the number of argument occurences and values allowed like so:

```rust
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser)]
pub struct Args {
    #[clap(short, long, value_parser, num_args = 1.., value_delimiter = ' ')]
    pub files: Vec<String>,
  }

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    println!("files: {:?}", args.files);
}
```

This will allow both

```
cargo run -- --files hello world
```

and

```
cargo run -- --files hello --files world
```

Specifying the `value_delimiter` is not strictly neccessary here, but I just wanted to point out that you can use different characters as delimiters like this.

If you also want to allow empty arrays beeing passed, you can change the `num_args` attribute like so `num_args = 0..`.

Comment: Is it possible to pass `["hello", "--files", "world"]` as the list? i.e., can you have a double-dash argument be interpreted literally instead of as a flag?